# Will there be any differences which affect photography when running Windows on a Mac?

Tags: windows, macintosh, computer-hardware

This might not be the best place to ask, but I'm wondering if anyone knows if there might be a difference in screen quality on my iMac when I'm in bootcamp Windows or OSX.

The reason I ask is because I made the mistake some time back to fork out for a Mac. It's not my thing and I know comfortably that I can make a better machine in a PC. But the deed is done and money is short. So I've put windows on the mac, and thinking of shifting my photography software to the windows partition. I've not calibrated the screen yet in mac (seemed to be excellent as factor setting) and I'm sure there might be some DPI issue maybe?

The reason I asked here is to get the perspective of photographers rather than just computer enthusiasts, as my main aim is to move all my photog software across. Hope this clears up why I posted here.

Comment: It's the same hardware that they use in windows machines so there shouldn't be any problems.  DPI can be set in the Desktop properties.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running Windows on a Mac which is really better suited to a site like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) where it may have already been asked.

Comment: This questions should most likely be asked on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) - the SE site for Apple hardware and software questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Booting into Windows using BootCamp puts you in the Windows OS and that uses the Windows Color System (WCS) to color manage the display. Mac OS uses ColorSync.  Both OS's use seperate Display profiles which are calculated and applied in different ways.  WCS using CIEcam02 and ColorSync uses the ICC v2 method.  So to answer your question...yes and no.  Yes they will be different, but no they can be made to match.  You must do this yourself and assume these are completely different computers.  WCS will render out of gamut colors differently than ColorSync, so take that into account when attempting to get them to match.  Also the perceptual rendering of both systems will be different so don't use those as a comparison.  Stick to Relative Colorimetric Rendering intent.

Comment: Thanks @R-Hall this seems to have set me in the right direction and made me think about things I hadn't yet consider. (OS colour Management)